# Node, Express with Typescript - class based or function based?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am new to node and typescript. I watched some tutorials explaining developing rest API using node, express with typescript in both class-based and function-based. I got some doubts there

- Is it mandatory to go with class-based if we are using typescript or
  can we use function-based too?
- can we use the class-based implementation in JS also?
- what is the difference or advantage (am aware of OOP) of using both
  class-based and function-based implementation?

Comment: 1. no. 2. yes. 3. The way you skin the cat.

Comment: Decorators don’t work with stand-alone functions. This is partly why frameworks like nestjs require classes so they can use decorators to expose data for validation, documentation, and similar. You can absolutely use stand alone functions, but be aware you can’t get features that you would get from nestjs or tsoa. Opinion, it’s easier without classes and without dependency injection.

Comment: Voting to close this as opinion-based is wrong because the first two questions are purely factual. 1: no. 2: yes as stated by @Nishant